# Display an author's posts on his own author page

Tags: posts, query-posts

I have a blog that publish articles of any philosophers.Each philosopher has a special page that includes information about him.

I've created a post type called *philosopher*. I want to display the title of each philosopher's articles under his page, but because every philosopher has many articles, I only want to display 10 articles and show the other articles on another page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the default author.php page to do this. If you don't have one, make a copy of index.php and rename it author.php

Now, use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) to include your custom post type in the author pages. This code goes in functions.php

```
function cpt_on_author_page( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_author() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'philosopher' ) );
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 10 );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cpt_on_author_page' );
```

Comment: Please leave feedback. This question remains open. Did any of the answers solve your issue? If so, accept the appropriate answer by clicking on the check mark next to it. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

paste this code in a template

```
    <?php
//if a certain page, then display posts authored by the logged in user
$page_title = 'Contributors Page';
if ( is_user_logged_in()  && is_page($page_title) ) {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  echo 'User ID: ' . $current_user->ID . "\n";
  $args=array(
    'author' => $current_user->ID,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish, private',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'caller_get_posts'=> 1
  );
  $my_query = null;
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    echo 'Your Posts';
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
      <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>
      <?php
    endwhile;
  }
  wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
}
?>
```

Comment: why you edit my question? my blog have not any Contributor and i'm admin ! see thid link: http://safirfilm.ir/persons/mostafarezvani